# Searching of a word in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, text

The program has to output if there is **word** in a **string**, but letters of the word has to be **in sequence.**

So for instance string = 'my**name**is**maria**', word = '**namemaria**'.
When I check if there is this word in a string

```
if word in string:
    print(word)
```

Programm finds **'namemaria'** in a string and outputs it.

But I want it to output a word just when letters of that word are in a sequence in the string. So for instance for the same string words '**nameis**' (string = 'my**nameis**maria') or '**ismaria**' (string = myname**ismaria**') would output the word.

Comment: Hmm. This is exactly how you would do that. Is there more to this script that we don't see?

Comment: No, this is the whole script.